# Read-Host with multiple colors

Tags: powershell

In one of my powershell functions, I want to gather input from the user, but first I need to give some instructions.  I'd like to print a line or two in the console with different colors.

```
function myFunction(){
    param(
        [string]$directions = $(read-host "Please answer the questions according to your opinion`nYour answers must be Star Wars-based." -foregroundcolor "Magenta"),
        [string]$robot = $(read-host "What is your favourite robot" -foregroundcolor "Yellow"),
        [string]$spaceship = $(read-host "What is your favourite spaceship" -foregroundcolor "Green")
    )
    write-host "Favourite Robot = " + $robot
    write-host "Favourite Spaceship = " + $spaceship
}
#call the function
myFunction
```

In the function above I have a newline to keep the directions on separate levels, but I want the first line of this text to be one colour and the second line to be another colour.

Also, `-foregroundcolor` doesn't work here - it just prints literally.

I can't put a `write-host` before the `param` statement or I would put the directions there (I know how to do *this* with multiple colours).

Comment: `Read-Host` does not have a `-ForegroundColor` parameter.

Comment: You've answered your own question, you need to do it with `Write-Host`. Fun fact, it can be done despite your reservations.

Comment: So you just need to use `Write-Host "Some text" -ForegroundColor -nonewline; Read-Host`

Comment: ex: `Write-Host "This Is " -ForegroundColor RED -NoNewline; Write-Host "asking for coloured input: " -ForegroundColor YELLOW -NoNewline; Read-Host;`

Comment: I know it can be done with `write-host` but how do I display the `write-host` before the parameters are retrieved?

Comment: oh.  I can put `write-host` right in the `$()` for the variable...

Comment: You can, you are probably best keeping the read-host calls outside the parameter set. If you are not passing the values into the function there is no need for them to be parameters, instead just call read-host inside the function code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be struggling a little with the instructions in the comments so here... Unsure why you want a read host for instructions but that's cool.

```
function myFunction(){
    param(
        [string]$directions = $(Write-Host "Please answer the questions according to your opinion`nYour answers must be Star Wars-based.: " -ForegroundColor Magenta -NoNewline; Read-Host),
        [string]$robot = $(Write-Host "What is your favourite robot: " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline; Read-Host),
        [string]$spaceship = $(Write-Host "What is your favourite spaceship: " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline; Read-Host)
    )
    write-host "Favourite Robot = "$robot
    write-host "Favourite Spaceship = "$spaceship
}
```

Comment: Instructions are for me...  In my real function, I want to tell myself how to build a csv file just in case I forget later.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: No worries Brother, be sure to post any sections of code that you may have problems with for your CSV project. A tip is to state the desired outcome, what you have tried and the section of code that is not producing the desired outcome.